# Multiple case statements

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run a multi-case statement in postgresql but I have an error of

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Blue"

Here is my syntax - what do I need to do update to make this valid syntax?

```
Select
id
,case
  when empid = 1 then blue 
  when empid = 2 then green
  when empid = 3 then red
  else empid
 end as employeecolor
 From employees
```

Comment: Well, realize that the pseudo-column 'employeecolor' needs to be a single type. You're telling postgres on the one hand that the type should be an integer (since you will return `empid` itself, in some cases), but on the other hand, you're saying that the type is a string ('red', 'blue', etc). It can't be both.

Comment: @jmelesky - that is what I am after.  The column is an int, but I want it to return a string value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add `::text` to the case when, that is

```
Select
id
,case
 when empid = 1 then blue 
 when empid = 2 then green
 when empid = 3 then red
 else empid::text
end as employeecolor
From employees
```